# Python: threading multiple infinite loops at the same time

Tags: python, multithreading

In Python I am trying to get one infinite loop to start running parallel at the same time, a simple example would be:

```
from threading import Thread

def func(argument):
    while True:
        print(argument)

def main():
    Thread(target=func("1")).start()
    Thread(target=func("2")).start()
    Thread(target=func("3")).start()
    Thread(target=func("4")).start()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Right now only the first thread runs, so the result is:

```
1
1
1
1
....
```

And it should be:

```
1
2
3
4
....
```

I found several similar questions but none of the provided solutions seem to work for me, including using `join` on the threads.

So if anyone knows the solution to my problem it would be very much appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "In CPython, due to the Global Interpreter Lock, only one thread can execute Python code at once (even though certain performance-oriented libraries might overcome this limitation). If you want your application to make better use of the computational resources of multi-core machines, you are advised to use multiprocessing or concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor. However, threading is still an appropriate model if you want to run multiple I/O-bound tasks simultaneously." from [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#module-threading)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first Thread isn't starting. You are calling the `func` in `main` and attempting to set its return value as `target`, but it runs forever and the first Thread never gets created. You want:

```
from threading import Thread

def func(argument):
    while True:
        print(argument)

def main():
    Thread(target=func,args=("1",)).start()
    Thread(target=func,args=("2",)).start()
    Thread(target=func,args=("3",)).start()
    Thread(target=func,args=("4",)).start()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This will pass `func` as an object. Starting the thread will call that object with the tuple of args specified.

Answer (score 1):

You can define your own thread:

```
from threading import Thread

class MyThread(Thread):
    def __init__(self,argument, **kwargs):
        super(MyThread, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.argument = argument

    def run(self):
        while True:
           print self.argument

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyThread('1').start()
    MyThread('2').start()
    MyThread('3').start()
    MyThread('4').start()
```